# multitoc prevents adding lines for tocloft custom lists

Tags: table-of-contents

`\addcontentsline{ext}{level}{content}` doesn't seem to work correctly for nonstandard `ext` when `multitoc` is being used. In particular, the `.ext` file (`.thn` in the example below) doesn't seem to be generated at all (or touched, if it already exists).

Commenting out the `multitoc` import causes the custom list to get populated correctly. Commenting it back in causes the custom list to be blank again, even if the `.thn` file persists from a previous run.

`\addcontentsline{toc}...` works correctly in both cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} % <-- Doesn't seem to matter where this line goes
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlistof{things}{thn}{List of Things}
\newcommand{\thing}[1]{#1 -- #1\addcontentsline{thn}{things}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listofthings

\section{Things}

\thing{Foo}
\thing{Flang}
\thing{Bar}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Fake section}
\addcontentsline{thn}{things}{Fake Thing}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multitoc` redefines the kernel's `\@starttoc` and stores the original definition `\@multitoc@starttoc`, so one option is to restore the original meaning for the new list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof{things}{thn}{List of Things}
\newcommand{\thing}[1]{#1 -- #1\addcontentsline{thn}{things}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\let\@starttoc\@multitoc@starttoc
\listofthings
\makeatother

\section{Things}

\thing{Foo}
\thing{Flang}
\thing{Bar}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Fake section}
\addcontentsline{thn}{things}{Fake Thing}

\end{document}
```

[image]